# why does gcc linker choose older version of shared lib?

Tags: c++, linker

I'm puzzled. I have 2 versions of libssl.so in /lib:
`/lib/libssl.so.4` and `/lib/libssl.so.6`

Here is a stripped down minimal example -- I'm linking "nothing" with libssl -- the result being that it links to `libssl.so.4`. What determines this?

```
 $ g++ -o foo.so -shared -lssl

 $ ldd foo.so |grep ssl
 libssl.so.4 => /lib/libssl.so.4 (0xf7f04000)
```

Comment: Is `/lib/libssl.so` or `/usr/lib/libssl.so` a symbolic link to `/lib/libssl.so.4`?  Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840218/how-to-specify-the-library-version-to-use-at-link-time).

Comment: yes, you are correct, /usr/lib/libssl.so is a symlink to /lib/libssl.so.4 (actually to the real file to which /lib/libssl.so.4 is itself a symlink.) Repointing solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option  `-lssl` instructs the linker to look for the file named `libssl.so` or `libssl.a`. If all you have are `libssl.so.4` and `libssl.so.6`, then you would have a linker error.

Look for a symlink called "libssl.so" somewhere in your library directories, likely in /lib.

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized this. What threw me is that I expected the libssl.so symlink to be in the same directory as the actual files (which was /lib), but it was actually in /usr/lib, and of course pointed to the .so.4 version in /lib. Repointing it was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Option `-lssl` looks for `linker` library name, in that case it is `libssl.so`. Typically libssl.so would be a symlink pointing to `soname` library or `real` name library whith which actual linking is done. You should repoint `libssl.so` symlink to correct version of using lib.

More about shared labrary naming you can read [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#AEN46).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly correct. I'd like to have marked this and @Cubbi's both as the selected answer but I had to choose one.