# GNU linker, the -l flag and implicit rules

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I'm fiddling around with GCC, trying to understand the various possibilities for linkage.

These are my questions:

1. Let's say I have two files `tools.c` and `tools.h`, and I create an archive `libtools.a` (containing `tools.o`).

   Now I have some `prog.c`, a program which includes `tools.h` and uses some of its functions.

   are the following commands equivalent?

   `gcc -Wall prog.c libtools.a -o prog`

   `gcc -Wall prog.c -ltools -o prog`
2. regarding the `-l` flag (`man ld` wasn't of much use unfortunately):

   a. What is the implicit pattern matching rule? -lX means *"find the file named libX.a"*?

   b. Does `-l` have any real importance in the linking process besides finding the library lazily (closely related to 1 I guess)?

   c. How do I link a library named `lib.a` or `tools.paz`?

Answer (score 0):

Using -l you link dynamically, using the filename you link statically. I suggest you read the manpage of ld, which explains all this in detail.

Comment: it appears under `-l`? about the static\dynamic, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840218/how-to-specify-the-library-version-to-use-at-link-time the chosen answer says using -l and the filename are interchangeable, if I didn't misunderstand it.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156055/gcc-static-linking-only-some-libraries/4156166#4156166