# Link against shared library with SONAME

Tags: gcc, linker, openssl, clang, ld

How can I force the gcc linker to link against a given version (soname) of a shared library on the system?

I need this to enforce that the version of openssl that is `#include`'ed matches the version that is linked, on any system, even if multiple versions of openssl are installed. To find the ABI version, my configure script first compiles and runs a program that extracts the SONAME from the headers:

```
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  printf(SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER);
  return 0;
}
```

The `SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER` contains the `so` version string, e.g. `0.9.8` or `1.0.2k` or `1.1.0`. But how do I tell `gcc` to link against this version of `libssl` or `libcrypto` rather than just any `-lssl`?

I tried ["in situ" linking](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/build_a_shared_library_using_gcc.html), so that instead of linking with `gcc main.c -lcrypto` we use:

```
gcc main.c libcrypto.so.1.1.0
```

However it seems the linker `libcrypto.so.1.1.0` cannot be found:

```
gcc: error: libcrypto.so.1.1.0: No such file or directory
```

I guess the system only searches in the standard locations when using the `-l` flag. Is there a better way to make my software link against `libcrypto.so.1.1.0`?

Comment: I think that what you wrote asks gcc to try to COMPILE libcrypto.so.1.1.0, rather than link it. There is a way of compiling the files in stages, then linking afterwards.

Comment: @ThomasHedden: your assumption is wrong. If you passed an absolute path to a shared object there it would link to it perfectly fine.

Comment: When linking like this: `gcc main.c libcrypto.so.1.1.0`, then `libcrypto.so.1.1.0` needs to be on the path and on the link/loader path. You can perform `gcc main.c /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1.0 -o my_prog` to help with the compile problem, but I am not sure what will happen at runtime. At runtime, you may need tricks like `LD_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1.0 ./my_prog`. I also know using the staic archive works as expected: `gcc main.c /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.a -o my_prog`. I use it frequently to avoid all the runtime link problems.

Answer (score 1):

To select the correct version of the openssl shared libraries use:

```
gcc main.c -l:libssl.so.1.0.0 -l:libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

The key to answering this question is "how do I control ld so that is links the correct version of a shared library?".

The correct way to pass a linker flag (a command line parameter to ld) using the gnu compilers (gcc, g++, gdc, etc...) is to use the normal ld parameter prefixed with "-l". For example -lssl or -L/usr/local/lib.

Edit: As per [How to specify the library version to use at link time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840218/how-to-specify-the-library-version-to-use-at-link-time) you can read the manual for ld with:`man ld`.