# How to specify the library version to use at link time in eclipse?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I have a **C++** project in **Eclipse Juno** (Service Release 2) on **Linux**.

I need to reference a third party library, but its name includes the library's version:

> libThirdParty.so.**10.1**

I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840218/how-to-specify-the-library-version-to-use-at-link-time). But it seems I have an old version of ld, and it doesn't work.
(I checked the man page)

I tried using the library's full name (path/name) but I don't know where to add it because it is not working.

I can not create a symbolic link of the library without the version.

In eclipse, Where should I reference the full library name? Is there another way to reference the library?

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us why you can't use symlinks we can find another way to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coworker helped me to solve this:

1. Right Click on the Project => Properties => C/C++ Build => Settings
2. Under GCC C++ Linker => Miscellaneous: Write the full name of your library, including the library path. Similar to the indications on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3840318/752842) for building with GCC.

Answer (score 0):

In the project explorer select your project and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will popup the properties window.

[image]

Then, under `C/C++ -> Settings` in the `Tool Settings Tab` select `Linker -> Libraries` click on the button add and write the library name-version you want to link to.

**Warning**: Be aware that in a Linux system exist a thing named **[soname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname)** for shared libraries, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839756/how-do-applications-resolve-to-different-versions-of-shared-libraries-at-run-tim) for a detailed explanation about it.

### **Edit: To the comments**

The thing is the linker will look for a file named `lib<name>.so` since your library's name is `libThirdParty.so.10.1` and don't ends with `.so` don't match this pattern. **This is not a problem you can solve with eclipse, this is a general linux behaviour**. If your library name were libThirdParty.10.1.so (note the trailing .so) then you could use `ThirdParty.10.1` as the library name in the libraries eclipse field.

Linux use this name convention in order to make easier handle various version of he same lib installed in the system. **What you want to do can't be done without use a symbolic link or rename the library to `libThirdParty.10.1.so`.**

Comment: I am not used to Linux, I normally work on Windows. From your warning I gather I need to install the shared library? I thought I could do like in windows that I get a dll from the source control and I can reference it. In the post I linked gcc supports receiving the full name of the file, the problem is that I don't know where to do that in Eclipse. When I add libThirdParty.so.10.1 in the field you pointed, it fails to build.

Comment: If the lib is not installed you also have to add the search directory for that library. Hence you have to add the directory where the lib are to the field `Library search path`, below the field I pointed.

Comment: I added the path and it is finding another library in the same folder, but the other file doesn't have the version number.

Comment: According to the warning I pointed later, you can put a symbolic link to the library you want. The symbolic link must be named as `libThirdParty.so`, this would be the soname. This symlink goes in the same folder you have your library. The other file is "recognized" due to it's name match it's soname.

Comment: In my question I indicated I couldn't use an alias. I meant by it symbolic link, I updated the question so it is more clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added some explanation ant the end of the answer.