# why are there duplicate/triplicate folders in anaconda/lib with same sizes but just a little bit different names?

Tags: anaconda

After I install OpenCV on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I realized that there are triplicate folders in anaconda/lib directory. Should I delete them?

[image: anaconda/lib folder]

Comment: No, do not delete them. These are different versions of the library that other programs may link to. If you do `ls -la` on that folder, you will see that two of the files are "links" to the third, in other words, they don't take up any space.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839756/how-do-applications-resolve-to-different-versions-of-shared-libraries-at-run-tim

Answer (score 0):

If you want to free up space, and `anaconda` uses a lot of disk space, you can do:

`conda clear -all`

This will remove stored, but already installed `tarballs`, old `packages` that were upgraded and are kept "just in case!", and free up the `svn cache`, `hg cache`, `git cache`, and `source cache`.